# MS Server 2019 Exchange

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2019, exchange-2019

I need some advice as I am a new ms server admin from a networks background. Essentially a client uses outlook to connect to their external imap account. But I would like the server to do this and the clients connect to the local server. I just need to be pointed in the right direction as I'm not sure on all the terminology. I was looking at relay but getting confused. Thanks Kindly.

Comment: What server? What do you have in place? What terminology?

Comment: Hi, it's Windows server 2019. I want that to connect to an external server (let's say outlook) to get the messages but have clients in the AD go to the internal exchange 2019 server. That way all emails for the same inbox are in one place and not over each users workspace. I'm guessing it's possible but I've never set it up before. So I'm asking is there any specific I need to do to enable it. I'm looking online but I'm not sure what MS guys call this type of exchange server. Is it relay? In which case I can work from there.

Comment: What you're looking for is a mail aggregator from what I understand. You won't get mail unless it's meant for your server and from what you're explaining mail isn't meant for your server but rather for a third party and you would like to mirror its content. For instance you could just setup forward rules on the third party.

Comment: Ah I'm with you, it's clicked now. Thanks Kindly this is what I was after.